# Is there a way to keep elements fixed in some point of a image that have object-fit: cover property?

Tags: html, css

I have a image in 16:9 (1920 x 1080) of a draw with some led light strips on it.

My objective is to implement a div of a gradient color to simulate a light effect, but I can only make this when the image is static on the background.
When I implement a `object-fit: cover;` property, the light div doesn't keep his position on the right area.

I have already tried to use `background-image` instead of `<img>` tag and tried to create a wrapper with `position relative` and `absolute`. Also, I'm using only responsive values into the css (percentages and viewport).

I think that the problem is in the fact that the `object-fit: cover` adjusts the image with zooms, and the div image doesn't follow that.

That's the image I'am using on this project. There's already a pink light coming out the LED strips on the draw, and I'm trying to make a new light above the pink one with a div.

[image]

This green light is the div that I'm trying to put above the pink light:
[image]

```
      .cafe-image div.left-light {
        background: linear-gradient(
          to top,
          rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
          rgba(101, 221, 137, 0.671)
        );
        width: 40%;
        height: 30%;

        transform: skew(28deg) rotate(15deg);

        position: absolute;
        top: 8.9%;
        left: -4.8%;
      }
```

It is not perfectly positioned, but I'm just trying to keep this green light on the right spot:
[image]

...But when I resize the tab, that green light just change his position:
[image]

In short, I would like to leave this div of the green light always in that specific point of the image, no matter the page size.

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .cafe-image {
        position: relative;
      }

      .cafe-image img {
        object-fit: cover;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .cafe-image div.left-light {
        background: linear-gradient(
          to top,
          rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
          rgba(101, 221, 137, 0.671)
        );
        width: 40%;
        height: 30%;

        transform: skew(28deg) rotate(15deg);

        position: absolute;
        top: 8.9%;
        left: -4.8%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="cafe-image">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/jq6xMxMC/cafe.jpg"/>

      <div class="left-light"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way would be to use another image of the same size , so object-fit would be used for both with same results.

here an example with for example an svg with a gradient and mix-blend-mode to mix both images:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div,
div img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block
}

div {
  display: grid;/* i use grid to pile image, you can use absolute too */
}

img {/* lets put image in the same grid cell and blend them with the page */
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%221919%22%20height%3D%22963%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20style%3D%22%0D%0Adisplay%3Ablock%3B%0D%0Awidth%3A1963px%3B%0D%0Aheight%3A963px%3B%0D%0Abackground%3A%20linear-gradient%2876.5deg%2C%20transparent%2040.25%25%2C%20white%2040.5%25%29%2C%20linear-gradient%2815.5deg%2C%20transparent%2064.5%25%2C%20white%2065%25%29%2Clinear-gradient%2815deg%2Ctransparent%2020%25%20%2C%20rgb%28101%2C%20221%2C%20137%29%2060%25%29%3B%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Crect%20width%3D%221919%22%20height%3D%22963%22%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%220%22%20fill%3D%22transparent%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwLqP.jpg"></div>
```

Here is the code of the SVG embed  :

```
<svg width="1919" height="963" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="
display:block;
width:1963px;
height:963px;
background: linear-gradient(76.5deg, transparent 40.25%, white 40.5%), linear-gradient(15.5deg, transparent 64.5%, white 65%),linear-gradient(15deg,transparent 20% , rgb(101, 221, 137) 60%);">
  <rect width="1919" height="963" x="0" y="0" fill="transparent" />
</svg>
```

you can use your own images then use mix-blend-mode, a png or gif or whatever you fill confident with, the idea is to use image of the same size to follow together the object-fit rule ;)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div,
div img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}

div {
  display: grid; /* i use grid to pile image, you can use absolute too */
}

img {
  /* lets put image in the same grid cell and blend them with the page */
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;

  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}
div img:nth-child(3) {
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%221919%22%20height%3D%22963%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20style%3D%22%0D%0Adisplay%3Ablock%3B%0D%0Awidth%3A1963px%3B%0D%0Aheight%3A963px%3B%0D%0Abackground%3A%20linear-gradient%2876.5deg%2C%20transparent%2040.25%25%2C%20white%2040.5%25%29%2C%20linear-gradient%2815.5deg%2C%20transparent%2064.5%25%2C%20white%2065%25%29%2Clinear-gradient%2815deg%2Ctransparent%2020%25%20%2C%20rgb%28101%2C%20221%2C%20137%29%2060%25%29%3B%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Crect%20width%3D%221919%22%20height%3D%22963%22%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%220%22%20fill%3D%22transparent%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwLqP.jpg">
  <img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%221919%22%20height%3D%22963%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20%3E%0D%0A%3Crect%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%220%22%20width%3D%221919%22%20height%3D%22963%22%20fill%3D%22rgba%280%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%29%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%0D%0A%3Cg%20transform%3D%22matrix%281%200%200%201%20928.5%20290.1%29%22%20style%3D%22%22%20%20%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3Ctext%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%20font-family%3D%22%27Open%20Sans%27%2C%20sans-serif%22%20font-size%3D%2240%22%20font-style%3D%22normal%22%20font-weight%3D%22normal%22%20style%3D%22stroke%3A%20none%3B%20stroke-width%3A%201%3B%20stroke-dasharray%3A%20none%3B%20stroke-linecap%3A%20butt%3B%20stroke-dashoffset%3A%200%3B%20stroke-linejoin%3A%20miter%3B%20stroke-miterlimit%3A%204%3B%20fill%3A%20rgb%280%2C0%2C0%29%3B%20fill-rule%3A%20nonzero%3B%20opacity%3A%201%3B%20white-space%3A%20pre%3B%22%20%3E%3Ctspan%20x%3D%22-267.45%22%20y%3D%2212.57%22%20style%3D%22font-family%3A%20%27Open%20Sans%27%2C%20sans-serif%3B%20font-weight%3A%20bold%3B%20fill%3A%20rgb%28255%2C255%2C255%29%3B%20white-space%3A%20pre%3B%20%22%3ELet%26apos%3Bs%20Test%20some%20TEXT%20HERE%20%3C%2Ftspan%3E%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fg%3E%0D%0A%3Cg%20transform%3D%22matrix%281%200%200%201%20254%20605.67%29%22%20style%3D%22%22%20%20%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3Ctext%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%20font-family%3D%22%27Open%20Sans%27%2C%20sans-serif%22%20font-size%3D%2218%22%20font-style%3D%22normal%22%20font-weight%3D%22normal%22%20style%3D%22stroke%3A%20none%3B%20stroke-width%3A%201%3B%20stroke-dasharray%3A%20none%3B%20stroke-linecap%3A%20butt%3B%20stroke-dashoffset%3A%200%3B%20stroke-linejoin%3A%20miter%3B%20stroke-miterlimit%3A%204%3B%20fill%3A%20rgb%28251%2C248%2C248%29%3B%20fill-rule%3A%20nonzero%3B%20opacity%3A%201%3B%20white-space%3A%20pre%3B%22%20%3E%3Ctspan%20x%3D%22-167.5%22%20y%3D%225.65%22%20style%3D%22fill%3A%20rgb%2837%2C176%2C37%29%3B%20white-space%3A%20pre%3B%20%22%3EOr%20here%20%3C%2Ftspan%3E%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fg%3E%0D%0A%3Cg%20transform%3D%22matrix%281%200%200%201%201382%20704.5%29%22%20style%3D%22%22%20%20%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3Ctext%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%20font-family%3D%22%27Open%20Sans%27%2C%20sans-serif%22%20font-size%3D%2223%22%20font-style%3D%22normal%22%20font-weight%3D%22normal%22%20style%3D%22stroke%3A%20none%3B%20stroke-width%3A%201%3B%20stroke-dasharray%3A%20none%3B%20stroke-linecap%3A%20butt%3B%20stroke-dashoffset%3A%200%3B%20stroke-linejoin%3A%20miter%3B%20stroke-miterlimit%3A%204%3B%20fill%3A%20rgb%28196%2C29%2C29%29%3B%20fill-rule%3A%20nonzero%3B%20opacity%3A%201%3B%20white-space%3A%20pre%3B%22%20%3E%3Ctspan%20x%3D%22-148.5%22%20y%3D%227.23%22%20%3EOr%20Maybe%20out%20there%3C%2Ftspan%3E%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fg%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E">
</div>
```

here is the code of that second SVG holdin texts :

```
<svg width="1919" height="963" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
<rect x="0" y="0" width="1919" height="963" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"></rect>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 928.5 290.1)" style=""  >
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="'Open Sans', sans-serif" font-size="40" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" ><tspan x="-267.45" y="12.57" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: bold; fill: rgb(255,255,255); white-space: pre; ">Let&apos;s Test some TEXT HERE </tspan></text>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 254 605.67)" style=""  >
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="'Open Sans', sans-serif" font-size="18" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(251,248,248); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" ><tspan x="-167.5" y="5.65" style="fill: rgb(37,176,37); white-space: pre; ">Or here </tspan></text>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1382 704.5)" style=""  >
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="'Open Sans', sans-serif" font-size="23" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(196,29,29); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" ><tspan x="-148.5" y="7.23" >Or Maybe out there</tspan></text>
</g>
</svg>
```

---

*aside the question : To turn the svg into a daturi, i used* https://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php

---

---

Edit about below comment using an object:

If you want to use an object to benefit svg interaction, you can instead set straight your svg inside the document instead wrapping it inside an object or even an img tag.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div,
div img,svg{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}

div {
  display: grid; /* i use grid to pile image, you can use absolute too */
}

img, svg {
  /* lets put image in the same grid cell and blend them with the page */
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}
div svg {
  mix-blend-mode: screen;

  object-fit:cover;
  max-height:100vh;
  max-width:100vw;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%221919%22%20height%3D%22963%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20style%3D%22%0D%0Adisplay%3Ablock%3B%0D%0Awidth%3A1963px%3B%0D%0Aheight%3A963px%3B%0D%0Abackground%3A%20linear-gradient%2876.5deg%2C%20transparent%2040.25%25%2C%20white%2040.5%25%29%2C%20linear-gradient%2815.5deg%2C%20transparent%2064.5%25%2C%20white%2065%25%29%2Clinear-gradient%2815deg%2Ctransparent%2020%25%20%2C%20rgb%28101%2C%20221%2C%20137%29%2060%25%29%3B%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Crect%20width%3D%221919%22%20height%3D%22963%22%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%220%22%20fill%3D%22transparent%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwLqP.jpg">
  <svg   viewbox="0 0 1919 963"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="1919" height="963" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"></rect>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 928.5 290.1)" style=""  >
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="'Open Sans', sans-serif" font-size="40" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" ><tspan x="-267.45" y="12.57" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: bold; fill: rgb(255,255,255); white-space: pre; ">Let&apos;s Test some TEXT HERE </tspan></text>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 254 605.67)" style=""  >
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="'Open Sans', sans-serif" font-size="18" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(251,248,248); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" ><tspan x="-167.5" y="5.65" style="fill: rgb(37,176,37); white-space: pre; ">Or here </tspan></text>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1382 704.5)" style=""  >
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="'Open Sans', sans-serif" font-size="23" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(196,29,29); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" ><tspan x="-148.5" y="7.23" >Or Maybe out there</tspan></text>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: That's good, but I have a question. How did you managed the SVG background position? I see that there's some values with deg, but isn't clear for me what each one do specifically.

Comment: @retr0 there is actually 3 gradients. 2 black ones on the top (first) to hide the area where the third one (green) should not be layed. Then mix-blend-mode will , kind of, erase the black parts. A png is probably a better option, so no need of mix-blend-mode ;) and you can easily produce your extra image layers from your graphic editor within the same file.

Comment: another question is: In my project, I'm using the background as a PNG, so the black parts of the windows are transparent. When I change the background of the body to blue for example, I expect that the outside of these windows turn into blue, while the lights comes out from the LEDS, but apparently this mix-blend-mode is making the whole thing blue. Is there a way to implement this mix-blend-mode only on the background image and the SVG to keep the body background clear?

Comment: If you make a translucide png, just do the green part, the black parts are to be transparent to avoid mix-blend-mode. black or white are about the only 2 colors you can use to blend entirely with the rest. I used an svg with a gradient because i had no tools to create an image. It was to demonstrate that 2 image of the same size will have their pixels position  matching and following object-fit.

Comment: I preferred to use this svg approach because I would be able to control the colors and the positioning with javascript. I was putting the mix-blend-mode in a div that included everything, instead of just in the svg.


I found this solution very good, but could you tell me how I could apply this to elements that are not images? For example: what if I wanted to put a text inside the window of the draw or something? When I set a parent div for the text with the same size as the drawing, the text inside the div still doesn't follow the object-fit.

Comment: @retr0 I added a snippet with  a third image with text fom an svg In the answser. Notice that that one gets another mix-blend-mode value to keep its colors.

Comment: Just one more question: It's possible to achieve this same result using ```<object>``` instead of ```<img>``` for the svg? I'm trying to do that to adjust the rgb numbers with JS but the lights come back to that initial problem of not following the background.

Comment: I created a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71861742/how-to-get-the-same-result-of-an-svg-inside-img-tag-using-object-or-pure-sv) with more details about this.

Comment: @retr0 I added a third snippet without embedding the SVG inside an img or object tag. I guess that if you wanted to use an object , it was also to be able to benefit from interaction with the SVG (where impossible if loaded via an img tag) . So the SVG can be directly inserted inside the container. It can be done manually, via an include on serverside or an appendChild() js on client side. If it is transparent, there is no need to blend it if it stands on top.