# How to get the same result of an svg inside <img> tag using <object> or pure <svg>?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to apply an svg above an image and keep his aspect-ratio with object-fit.
Both the svg and the image have the same size (100vw & 100vh), and they are positioned using position relative/absolute. I want to make this SVG interactive, but can only make this using tags like `<svg>`, `<object>` or `<iframe>`, because they allow me to access the elements in the JS.

When I apply the `<img>` with the configuration on CSS, works fine:

```
<body>
    <main class="full-viewport relative">
      <div class="full-viewport object-cover relative">
        <img class="full-viewport object-cover absolute" src="https://i.postimg.cc/j2CWcLQN/cafe-night.png" />

        <!-- works good - ideal positioning but can't have interactivity with js -->
        <img class="full-viewport object-cover absolute remove-white-background" src="../svg/left-light.svg" />
```

Image in full size:
[image]

Resized image:

[image]

The SVG follows the image in a way that the green light always keep above the right position.

But I want to interact with this light, and to get this, apparently I need to use a different tag like the pure `<svg>` inside the HTML or something like `<object>`

And there's the problem: When I use these specific tags, the SVG doesn't follow perfectly the image. I've already tried to use svg with `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes, but nothing changed.

Image in full size and with `<object>` tag:
[image]

Resized image (with `<object>` tag):
[image]

Full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/lightTest.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="full-viewport relative">
      <div class="full-viewport object-cover relative">
        <img class="full-viewport object-cover absolute" src="https://i.postimg.cc/j2CWcLQN/cafe-night.png" />

        <!-- works good - ideal positioning but can't have interactivity with js -->
        <img class="full-viewport object-cover absolute remove-white-background" src="../svg/left-light.svg" />

        <!-- doesn't work (object tag) - can interact with js but positioning doesn't follow the object-fit -->
        <!-- <object class="full-viewport object-cover absolute remove-white-background" data="../svg/left-light.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object> -->

        <!-- doesn't work (svg with preserveAspectRatio) - can interact with js but positioning doesn't follow the object-fit -->
        <!-- <svg class="full-viewport absolute remove-white-background" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="
        background: 
        linear-gradient(76deg, transparent 40.25%, white 40.5%), 
        linear-gradient(14.7deg, transparent 62.3%, white 0%),
        linear-gradient(-5deg, transparent 32% , rgb(50, 221, 137), rgb(0, 255, 255));">
          <rect x="0" y="0" fill="transparent" />
        </svg> -->
      </div>
    </main>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .absolute {
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .relative {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .full-viewport {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  
  .object-cover {
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  .remove-white-background {
    mix-blend-mode: darken;
  }
```

Left light svg:

```
<svg width="1920" height="1080" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="
width:1920px;
height:1080px;
background: 
linear-gradient(76deg, transparent 40.25%, white 40.5%), 
linear-gradient(14.7deg, transparent 62.3%, white 0%),
linear-gradient(-5deg, transparent 32% , rgb(50, 221, 137), rgb(0, 255, 255));">
  <rect width="1920" height="1080" x="0" y="0" fill="transparent" />
</svg>
```